# Выравнивание нескольких блоков по вертикали flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть контейнер высотою 100vh, в нем есть верхняя навигация, и один блок по середине. Не могу найти нужного свойство для такого.

```
<header style="height: 100vh">
    <nav>Top</nav>
    <div>Middle</div>
</header>
```

Comment: В заголовке написано же по вертикали)

Answer (score 0):

`align-items: center`:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  
  background: #ccc;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header style="height: 100vh">
    <nav>Top</nav>
    <div>Middle</div>
</header>
```

Или так, если второй блок по вертикали выравнять:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  
  background: #ccc;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
  margin:auto auto;
}
```

```html
<header style="height: 100vh">
    <nav>Top</nav>
    <div>Middle</div>
</header>
```

Вариант с `flex-direction:row`:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #ccc;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: baseline;
}
```

```html
<header style="height: 100vh">
  <nav>Top</nav>
  <div>Middle</div>
</header>
```